# Array that flags the last step of the user so i can identify where he left out my bot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset grouped by steps and userids, the steps are utilized so i can identify where my user passed through.

```
Input:
Unique Step | Grouped UserId
"Step 1"            Bunch of Userids
"Step 2"            Bunch of Userids
"Step 3"            Bunch of UserIds
```

That i got by running this line of code

```
df2=df.groupby(['Steps','UserPhones']).sum()
```

As i acessed the df2.index.values, i received the following array(next sample). The early data treatment was made to guarantee, that i only got unique userids in the "userid" position i[1] and i had a specific "Step" position i[0].

```
Input:
"Step 1"            A (Guranteed it only appears once)
"Step 1"            B
"Step 2"            A
"Step 2"            B
"Step 3"            A
"Step 3"            (B no longer appears)
"Step 4"            (A no longer appear)
```

What i want is to output an array, that brings userid A last step and userid b last step. Here is a sample.

```
Output:
"Step"    |  "UserId"
"Step3"              A
"Step2"              B
```

Would appreciate a little help on building up this specific df on numpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to apply only the list value, by changing up the first line of code to this

```
df2=df.groupby(['Steps']).UserPhones.unique().reset_index()
```

And after that was just a little bit of list camparison, and definition.